# How to display data in multiple text boxes by clicking on data grid

Tags: c#, datagrid

i have a data grid and some textboxes on same form. i want to populate textboxes by clicking on data grid. but it shows this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. here is my code for data grid click event

```
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
              textBox5.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            textBox1.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            textBox4.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            textBox6.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            textBox7.Text = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Try this`DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
            textBox2.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            textBox4.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            textBox5.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();`

Comment: it is showing this error: 
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: I am taking 5 textbox i think you need 7,so add it.